# Trying to understand how SyncLock Works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made a two static classes

```
NotInheritable Class gObject2
    Public Shared TestSyncLock As String = "test"
End Class

NotInheritable Class gObject3
    Public Shared TestSyncLock As String = "test"
End Class
```

Then I have two aspx

Synclock1.aspx:

```
Public Class SyncLock1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SyncLock gObject2.TestSyncLock
            Thread.Sleep(10000)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

Synclock2.aspx

```
Public Class SyncLock2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SyncLock gObject3.TestSyncLock
            SomeDiv.InnerHtml = "It works"
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

1. When I go to synclock1.aspx it spins for 10 seconds and shows a blank page as expected.
2. When I go to synclock2.aspx it spits out `it works`

Everything is good so far.

Now when I go to synclock1.apx and then in another browser got to synclock2.aspx, synclock2.aspx doesn't finish loading until synclock1.aspx finishes.

These are 2 different objects I'm locking with synclock, but it treats them the same.  Why is this?

Comment: What happens if you change one of the strings to `test123`? Perhaps `SyncLock` does a normal comparison rather than a reference comparison?

Comment: @VisualVincent I thought your suggestion was completely off-based, but when I changed the string from `test` to `test123` it worked.

Comment: Presumably it uses `Object.Equals` behind the scenes and that will test value equality for type `String`.  I would suggest that objects created specifically to lock on should just be type `Object`. If they exist solely to lock on then they shouldn't have any data because such data can have no useful purpose.

Comment: Like jmcilhinney says, a `System.Object` is the recommended thing to sync-lock. It can only be compared by its reference, thus two sync-locks must use _**the exact same instance**_ of the object in order for one of them to be blocked.

Comment: I agree, I just wished Microsoft would of documented it better. You can actually do a `synclock "test"` and it will function the same way. You don't even have to reference a variable/object. It's works like mutexes in that regard.

Comment: @VisualVincent and Henry, the probable reason for the string referential equality in between the two classes is that the string "test" is interned by the CLR pool.  See: [String.IsInterned Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: TnTinMn : Interesting... What you say is also confirmed by declaring two string variables with the same value and checking `String1 Is String2`.

Comment: Thanks TnTinmn, more light is shed. Someone sum all of this as an answer, so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SyncLock`statement takes an object reference as its argument. As the `String` type is a reference type, your code is satisfying that constraint. However, due to [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) in .Net, the literal value equality of the two separate `String` references is also causing referential equality between `gObject2.TestSyncLock` and `gObject3.TestSyncLock`.

From: [String.IsInterned Method - Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) (emphasis added)

> The common language runtime automatically maintains a table, called
>   the intern pool, which contains a single instance of each unique
>   literal string constant declared in a program, as well as any unique
>   instance of String you add programmatically by calling the Intern
>   method.
>
> The intern pool conserves string storage. **If you assign a literal
>   string constant to several variables, each variable is set to
>   reference the same constant in the intern pool instead of referencing
>   several different instances of String that have identical values.**

Since both `gObject2.TestSyncLock` and `gObject3.TestSyncLock` are pointing to the same `String` reference, `SyncLock gObject2.TestSyncLock` will block `SyncLock gObject3.TestSyncLock`.

The subject code is a good example of how string interning can cause unexpected behavior.  The article [Interning Strings and immutability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/22/interning-strings-and-immutability/) provides additional details on the mechanics of interning and also provides another example where interning can cause unexpected results.

So the moral of this story is to avoid using strings as the argument for `SyncLock`.  It is safer to use something like the following:

```
NotInheritable Class gObject2
     Public Shared TestSyncLock As New Object
End Class

NotInheritable Class gObject3
     Public Shared TestSyncLock As New Object
End Class
```